# What can be said about distribution which has a predictor in a class with VC dimension k?

Tags: distributions, predictive-models, vc-dimension

Suppose, a distribution D on X x {0, 1} has a predictor with 0 loss in a function class with VC dimension k < $\infty$. What does it say about this distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If f is the predictor with 0 loss, for any x, p(f(x) | x) = 1. The distribution is ``deterministic''.

Otherwise, we can not say anything. If  f is a predictor with 0 loss, the class of function {f} has VC dimension 0. So, any distribution which has a predictor with  loss \epsilon >= 0  has a predictor with loss \epsilon in a class of function with VC dimension 0.